# Yii2 GridView convert date format from mm/dd/yyyy

Tags: php, gridview, yii

I am trying to convert a date from yyyy-mm-dd to mm-dd-yyyy Yii2 GridView; however I don't know how the date function requires a timestamp, and I can't get a timestamp from this string.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
[
    'attribute' => 'created_at',
    'format' => ['datetime', 'php:m/d/Y H:i:s']
],
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: thanks for ur comment , going forward i will take care